# hyperledger different endorsment policies on different organisations

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Suppose we have two organisations (org1 and org2) each having one peer. They share a common channel, where a chaincode (cc) is installed.

To make a transaction from org1 -> org2 
- org1 needs to do checks on legacy db
- org2 needs to do different checks on a different legacy db

Is there a better solution, than doing all the stuff in the centralized sdk?

Comment: To make a transaction from org1 -> org2 
<ul>
<li> org1 needs to do checks on legacy db </li>
<li>org2 needs to do different checks on a different legacy db</li>
</ul>

Comment: Are you trying to make the legacy db checks from within the chaincode?  And of course the chaincode on each org's peer needs to call a different legacy db?